# Xcode close view controller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have two viewControllers parent and child, from parent I'm opening child viewController like this:

```
ClildVC *modal = [[ClildVC alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:modal animated:YES];
```

and when I return from child View to parent, I use this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I want, when returning to parent viewController it be refreshed (reloaded), like I open it first time.

Comment: put your refresh in `viewDidAppear`. It will run on the initial launch and when you ever come back to that view.

Comment: If that doesn't work, make the parent be a delegate of the child VC and dismiss the child VC from the parent VC using the delegate method. Then add your refresh code/method in the delegate method so the parent view will be refreshed before the child view is dismissed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your parentViewController in .h and .m add method

```
- (void)refreshData
{
    //refresh your data
}
```

in your childViewController type this

```
- (IBAction)backToParent
{
    YourParentController *parent = (YourParentController *)self.parentViewController;
    [parent refreshData];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated as of iOS6

You should use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` which was introduced in iOS5 in the child view controller after calling a data update on its parent view controller

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating with no nib file  and no bundle identifier.

So its looking for a non existent nib in a bundle that isn't there

either design the nib in IB (xcode 4) or storyboard (4.2 +) or programatically by using the designated initialiser for the modal view controller.